# Visual studio 2010 missing BI 2010 (SSDT 2010)

Tags: ssdt, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Where can I find a link to install SSIS 2010 ( SSDT 2010 or Business Intelligence 2010)

I have VS 2010 on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 is no longer supported for SQL Server Business Intelligence tools. You will not find a download link unless Google or some other site might have cached it somewhere.

You will need to [download Visual Studio 2012 SSDT-BI or 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856966.aspx), these support BI projects for SQL Server 2012 and 2014 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

BI 2010 came with SQL 2012 standard edition install file. I was able to install.
Thanks!